# Existence of isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ a ring with unit, suppose if $xy = 0$, then $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, for $x,y \in R$. $(*)$

Fixed $x \in R-\{0\}$, denote $Rx = \{rx : r \in R\}$, a simple exercise is show $R \cong Rx$ (ring isomorphism) if, and only if, x is invertible.

That is, the converse is easy. Suppose x is invertible, so define $\phi: R \rightarrow Rx$ by $\phi(r) = x^{-1}rx$, it's easy to check $\phi$ isomorphism. Reciprocal is a little more complicated. If $e$ is the unit of $R$, let $\phi$ a isomorphism from $R$ to $Rx$, we have $\phi(e)$ is the unit of $Rx$, because $rx \in Rx$, $\phi$ is bijection, then exist $t \in R$ such that $\phi(t) = rx$ and $rx\phi(e) = \phi(t)\phi(e) = \phi(t) = rx$, the second equality follow $\phi$ is homomorphism, the same idea show $\phi(e)rx = rx$. Denote $\phi(e) = r_ex$, we have $$r_exrx = rxr_ex = rx, \forall r \in R$$

Take $r = x$, so $x^2r_ex = x^2$ using $(*)$ we have $r_ex = e$

Take $r = r_e$, so $r_ex = r_exr_ex = r_e(xr_e)x$, using $(*)$ twice we have $xr_e = e$

Therefore $r_e = x^{-1}$

My question: If $R \cong Rx$, $x \neq 0$ (so $x$ is invertible), then exist a unique isomorphism such that realize $R \cong Rx$, that is, $\phi$ from $R$ to $Rx$, $\phi(r) = x^{-1}rx$ is the unique isomorphism.

My attempt: Is it true? I can't see a counter example.  If we define $\psi: R \rightarrow R$, by $\psi(r) = \phi(r)x^{-1}$, of course $\phi(r) = \psi(r)x$, i.e., for $r \in R$, $\phi(r) = sx$, for some $s \in R$, then $\psi(r) = s$.

$\psi$ is bijection, but it isn't a homomorphism, I've tried show $\psi(r) = x^{-1}r$, $\forall r \in R$. But it wasn't successful.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean if $x,y\neq 0$ then $xy\neq 0$ right? not the other way around! the way you wrote it is trivially true for every ring!

Comment: $Rx$ is NOT a ring for all $x\in R$. So there is no sense in having a ring isomorphism btween $R$ and $Rx$ (example $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $x=2$). First thing you should investigate is $Rx$ is a ring with $x$ being its identity if and only if $x$ is a unit. From there it should be easy to finish.